# Error when returning prepared statement result

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have the following function:

```
class Forums {
        public function getForum($id) {
            $database = new Database();
            $mysqli = $database->databaseConnection();
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, description FROM forums WHERE id = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt;
        }
}
```

I invoke it like this:

```
$forums = new Forums();
$result = $forums->getForum($_GET["id"]);
$result->bind_result($name, $description);
$result->fetch();
```

And then, since it returns only one row, call `$name` or `$description` whenever I need it.

However I get the following error in my browser (Chrome):

> Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data."

This does not happen if I get rid of the function and connect to database and create prepared statement directly in the file where the result is used.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) issue. Object that holds `$mysqli` is destroyed directly after `getForum()` method execution. So open DB connection is destroyed at this moment too. But `$result->fetch();` need to be connection still open.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. But how would I go about resolving this issue while still keeping it object oriented?

Comment: You code is not compatible with encapsulation rules (in my opinion). While `getForum()` hides database interaction, it should *fully* hide it inside. Return an clean array it you can (I mean memory limits). The other way is to pass any callback inside `getForum()` to iterate database rows with some action using `$stmt->fetch()`.

Comment: You are right - solved the problem by refactoring my function to return array with final results. Thanks for tips!